# java scanner ignores ^ Caret

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am attempting to use java scanner with the following set of delimiters `& = ~ ^` (ampersand, equals, tilde, caret) by using method `useDelimiter("&|=|~|^");`.

All the delimiters work OK apart from `^` which is ignored: why is that?

I cannot see why in the Scanner documentation.

Comment: The "squiggle" is called "tilde" (~) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde

Comment: i thought so... just didnt think i could spell tilde correctly though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `^`, like this: `useDelimiter("&|=|~|\\^")`. That's because `^` is a meta-character in regular expressions, and the `String` parameter of `useDelimiter()` ends up being compiled to a regex [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Equivalently, you could write the delimiter like this, in this case there's no need to escape the `^`: `useDelimiter("[&=~^]")`

Comment: i had already tried this approach and it didnt work... however i think this is because the ^ was immediately followed by =. i believe if two delimeters follow each other then using a list of single delimeters doesnt work... or maybe two delimeters next to each other ends up with getting null in the token

Comment: In a character class (the thing surrounded by `[]` in a regular expression), a `^` means negation if found at the beginning. For example this `[^abc]` means: match anything _but_ a or b or c. If the caret appears in any other position in a character class, it's interpreted as a normal character

Answer (score 2):

`^` is a reserved symbol in regular expression, so you need to escape it: `\\^`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an alternation you could use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
"[&=~^]"
```

Since `^` is not special inside a character class (except at the start) it doesn't need escaping.